# Make a bootstrap for matrix in R with 100 replications (bootstrap correlation matrices)

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, correlation, boot

Here I show the dataset.

```
library(igraph)
vetor <- c(1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 3, 2:15, 1, 5, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3 )
matrix(vetor, 7, 7)
matrix<-matrix(vetor, 7, 7)
matcor <- cor(matrix, method = "spearman")

matrixnetwork = graph.adjacency(matcor, mode="undirected", weighted = 
TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
plot(matrixnetwork)
```

I need calculated the bootstrap correlation matrices by randomly permuting the order of values within each Region of Interest, and then computed the values of graphs for each of the bootstrap matrices. I will run subsequent comparison analyzes (t test)

```
Corr_fun = function(matrix, indices) {
return(cor(matrix, method= "spearman")) }
BIboot= boot(matrix, statistic= Corr_fun, R = 100)

AIBOOT<-BIboot[["t"]]
```

this form return a matrix 49x100, when I run the the command below, say: Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted,  :
not a square matrix.

```
g_boot <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(AIBOOT, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
```

Furthermore, it returns me with repeated values

[image]

I try too:

```
library(bootstrap)
theta = function(matrix, indices) {
return(as.matrix(matrix)) }  #funcao para centralidade
BOOTSAVE<-bootstrap(matrix, nboot = 100, theta)
```

here is result:
[image]

I try too permute for graph, here "matrixnetwork" is from comand for adjacency_matrix, but this form I need do 1 by 1, I need it 100x in a way that makes it easy to measure the graph and make subsequent comparisons:

```
matrixnetwork2<-permute(matrixnetwork, sample(vcount(matrixnetwork)))
```

I try this form, seems to work, here "aibi_imuno_BI_1" is my data. I donta put "cm <- cormat[indices, indices]", because this was repeating the same area 2x

```
N <- 7L set.seed(2023) 
R <- 100L 
BIboot <- vector("list", length = R) 
for(i in seq.int(R)) { indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE) 
BIboot[[i]] <- cor(aibi_imuno_BI_1, method = "spearman") } 
 g_boot_list <- lapply(BIboot, graph_from_adjacency_matrix, mode = 
"undirected", weighted = TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE) plot 
 (g_boot_list[[1]])
```

after correction is this form:

```
# BOOT 1
N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIboot <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
BIboot[[i]] <- cor(aibi_imuno_BI_1[indices, ], method = "spearman")
}
g_boot_list <- lapply(BIboot, graph_from_adjacency_matrix, mode = 
"undirected", weighted = TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
plot (g_boot_list[[1]])
```

Here I have 100 bootstrap correlation matrices by randomly permuting

Finally I try:

```
 #############BOTPERMUTATION FORMA 2 ####################
N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIPERMUT<- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIPERMUT[[i]] <- permute(matrixnetwork, 
 sample(vcount(matrixnetwork)))  
}

plot (BIPERMUT[[1]])
degree(BIPERMUT[[1]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)

 #################FORMA 3 #######################
 N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIboot2 <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIboot2[[i]] <- matrixnetwork
}

plot (BIboot2[[1]])
degree(BIboot2[[1]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you please post code or console output instead of pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted  bootstrap function is not sub-setting the input correlation matrix, it is repeating the same calculation on the entire matrix `R` times. And the way it is called is wrong too. The question's code is bootstrapping function `cor`, not the matrix.

Here is a solution.
First create a results list `BIboot`. Then populate the list by bootstrapping the correlations:

- sample `N` rows numbers with replacement;
- create a matrix of those rows and columns;
- compute the statistic of interest.

After the correlations list is created, use it to create a list `g_boot_list` of the `R` undirected graphs in the final `lapply` loop.

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

N <- 7L
fakecors <- runif(choose(N, 2))
cormat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- fakecors
diag(cormat) <- 0
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(t(cormat))]

set.seed(2023)
R <- 10L
BIboot <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  cm <- cormat[indices, indices]
  BIboot[[i]] <- cor(cm, method = "spearman")
}
g_boot_list <- lapply(BIboot, graph_from_adjacency_matrix, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But I need 100 permutations matrices (I think this is  equals) that can be read by command; graph.adjacency(matcor, mode="undirected", weighted = TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
The way above ends up giving the same error: Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted, : not a square matrix.

How can I execute the command for each version of the matrix?

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro Done, see if the changed code solves the problem.

Comment: IS RIGHT! RUN! But I have one question. In this case, can I replace cormat, with my primary matrix from which I want it to make all the correlations? or I replace it with the already correlated matrix. I think it makes more sense to do the 100 correlations of the primary matrix. Than correlate 100x the correlation matrix. Because I need calculated the bootstrap correlation matrices by randomly permuting the order of values within each Region of Interest.

Comment: I try this form, seems to work, here "aibi_imuno_BI_1" is my data. I donta put "cm <- cormat[indices, indices]",  because this was repeating the same area 2x

N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIboot <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIboot[[i]] <- cor(aibi_imuno_BI_1, method = "spearman")
}
g_boot_list <- lapply(BIboot, graph_from_adjacency_matrix, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
plot (g_boot_list[[1]])

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro Please don't post code in comments, edit the question with it. The code in your 2nd comment doesn't seem right, though I believe you should bootstrap the original matrix. Can you edit the question with the new info?

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro Try the 2nd code with `BIboot[[i]] <- cor(aibi_imuno_BI_1[indices, ], method = "spearman")`. (Only row indices)

Comment: Sorry for cod in comments, this last cod is run! Perfect, go to add in the question.

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro I'm glad it helped. I have edited your edit, the code you posted in the answer is now at the bottom of the question.